# How to find fundamental matrix of matrix differential equations?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, fundamental-solution

The Matrix Differential equation $$ \frac{dX(t)}{dt} =X(t) \cdot A $$

where

$$X(t)=\large \begin{pmatrix} x_1(t)\\x_2(t)\\x_3(t)\\x_{4}(t)\end{pmatrix},$$
$$A=\large \begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0&0\\-k_{1}&0&k_{2}&0\\0&0&0&1\\k_{3}&0&-k_{4}&0\end{pmatrix}.$$
In here, $k_i\in \mathbb{R} $, but they are ungiven.

Initial condition:
$$X(0)=\large \begin{pmatrix} x_{10}\\x_{20}\\x_{30}\\x_{40}\end{pmatrix},$$

We know that the solution is $X(t)=e^{At}X(0)$.

**The question I want to ask:**
How can we find/symbolize fundamental matrix of the equation?

Comment: Are you asking what is the matrix $e^{At}$?

Comment: I ask the fundamental matrix whose columns are linearly independent solutions of the system. Please see:https://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjN8ITKx7vUAhUMIpoKHVyiBhMQFggzMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFundamental_matrix_(linear_differential_equation)&usg=AFQjCNGezP0w_scdfKoHouwoODiweviFVw&sig2=8V7hx-15tXsBBrht-98ttA

Comment: On the other hand, can we calculate easily the matrix $e^{At}$?

Comment: If you reorganize the order of your lines and columns, your matrix take the form of a matrix with two $2 \times 2$ blocks of zeros.

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this besides writing up the question? Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part A:** "traditional solution"

let us re-organize system

$$\begin{pmatrix}\dot x_1(t)\\ \dot x_2(t)\\ \dot x_3(t)\\ \dot x_{4}(t)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0&0\\-k_{1}&0&k_{2}&0\\0&0&0&1\\k_{3}&0&-k_{4}&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1(t)\\x_2(t)\\x_3(t)\\x_{4}(t)\end{pmatrix}$$

by grouping the 2nd and the 4th equation, and, apart, the 1st and 3rd:

$$\tag{1}(a)\begin{cases}\dot x_2 & = & -k_1 x_1 +k_2 x_3\\ \dot x_4 & = & k_3 x_1 -k_4 x_3\end{cases} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (b)\begin{cases}\dot x_1 & = & x_2\\ \dot x_3 & = & x_4\end{cases} $$
Differentiating the LHSs and RHSs of (1)(a)

$$\tag{2}\begin{cases}\ddot x_2 & = & -k_1 \dot x_1 +k_2 \dot x_3\\ \ddot x_4 & = & k_3 \dot x_1 -k_4 \dot x_3\end{cases}$$

Taking into account (1)(b) in (2), gives

$$\tag{3}\begin{cases}(i)&\ddot x_2 & = & -k_1 x_2 +k_2 x_4\\ (ii)&\ddot x_4 & = & k_3  x_2 -k_4 x_4\end{cases}$$

Let us stop there for a while. If $k_2$ or $k_3$ are either zero or very small, you have two **uncoupled** harmonic oscillators. This case is illustrated, using results of the 2nd part, on the figure below. Have you seen this very important second order differential equation with sinusoidal solutions ?

If we are not in this case, it suffices to combine $k_4 \times (i) + k_2 \times (ii)$ to obtain

$$\tag{4}k_2 \ddot x_4 \ = \ -k_4 \ddot x_2 + (k_2 k_3 - k_1 k_4) x_2 $$

Now, if we differentiate twice (3)(i) and take (4) into account, we are left with a fourth order differential equation for function $x_2$ which isn't difficult to solve because its characteristic polynomial has the biquadratic form $ar^4+br^2+c=0.$

Having obtained $x_2$, it remains to plug it into (4) to get $x_4$, taking into account the initial conditions.

**Part B:** I have obtained a general form, not of $\exp(tA)$, but of $\exp(t\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is the following "shuffled form" of $A$:

$$\tag{5}\Omega=\left(\begin{array}{rr|rr} 0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\ \hline -k_{1}&k_{2}&0&0\\k_{3}&-k_{4}&0&0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{rr} 0&I\\B&0\end{array}\right)$$

(using block notation); it is clearly in correspondence with the separation (1)(a) / (1)(b) upwards.

What I have found is that, under the condition that matrix $B$ possesses a square root $C$, i.e. a matrix such that $C^2=B$, then:

$$\tag{6}\exp(t\Omega)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cosh(t C)&C^{-1}\sinh(tC)\\ C \sinh(t C)&\cosh(t C)\end{array}\right).$$

where $\sinh(C)$ and $\cosh(C)$ are resp. the matrix $\cosh$ and the matrix $\sinh$, defined by a series (see ([Hyperbolic cosine of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2068542))), in the same way the matrix exponential can be defined.

**Proof sketch of (6):** It comes from series expansion; in fact, powers of $\Omega$ have a rather simple general structure, depending on the parity of the exponent:

$$\Omega=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0&I\\C^2&0\end{array}\right) \ \ \implies \ \
\Omega^{2k}=\left(\begin{array}{cc} C^{2k}&0\\0&C^{2k}\end{array}\right) \  \ \text{and} \ \ \Omega^{2k+1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0&C^{2k+2}\\C^{2k}&0\end{array}\right)$$

$$\exp(t\Omega)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\tfrac{1}{n!}t^n\Omega^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\tfrac{1}{(2k)!}t^{2k}\Omega^{2k}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\tfrac{1}{(2k+1)!}t^{2k+1}\Omega^{2k+1}$$

[image]

Figure 1: $x_2$ in blue, $x_4$ in red in the case $k_2=k_3=0$.

See also (https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/57871/ExponentialExplicitSoTAC1993.pdf?sequence=1
).

Comment: Could you comment on the solution I have given with now a proof ?